# Edit HTML of woo commerce featured products widget

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to modify HTML code of woo-commerce featured product widget. Problem is that I can't find it inside my template folder/plugin folder.

Does someone knows how to modify  featured product widget of woo-commerce?

Answer (score 7):

This is modified via the **content-widget-product.php** template, located in `/woocommerce/templates/`.

To override this template, copy: `woocommerce/templates/content-widget-product.php` to `yourtheme/woocommerce/content-widget-product.php`, and make any necessary modifications in the copied file (not the original).

For information on correctly modifying Woocommerce templates, please [see the docs on overriding WooCommerce templates](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/).

Comment: You can have an upvote - I imagine it could have been downvoted because content-widget-product.php is a relatively new file and if they were running an older version of woocommerce they may not have had this file and err's solution would be the only option.

Answer (score 2):

I've done this with random products, but you can change whatever class you want, just change the file names...

**add to functions.php**

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'err_override_woocommerce_widgets', 15 );
function err_override_woocommerce_widgets() {
    if ( class_exists( 'WC_Widget_Random_Products' ) ) {
        unregister_widget( 'WC_Widget_Random_Products' );
        include_once( 'woocommerce/classes/class-wc-widget-random-products.php' );
        register_widget( 'err_WC_Widget_Random_Products' );
    }
}
```

*Note: don't forget to change the path, which is relative to functions.php!*

Copy

*wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/classes/widgets/class-wc-widget-random-products.php*

to

*wp-content/templates/%theme name%/woocommerce/classes/class-wc-widget-random-products.php*

*Note: change %theme name% to your theme name!*

Add the widget to your sidebar/footer/etc, change anything in your class in it's new place, and you're done.