# How can I hide WooCommerce price in widget using filters?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget, hide

I know I can use CSS to hide the price in the WooCommerce latest products widget, but it still shows a "-" for variable products, so I need to hide the price using filters.

I found this snippet that hides the price in the whole store:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'hide_price' , 99, 2 );

function hide_price( $price ) {
    $price = '';
    return $price;
}
```

But I only need to hide the price from content-widget-product.php (I'm trying to avoid editing the template file).

Comment: There is no way to hide the price with an filter for that specific widget. But you could try to override the [widget template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215984/edit-html-of-woo-commerce-featured-products-widget) and then remove the price call. Or you could remove the price via CSS or JavaScript on runtime.

Answer (score -1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', function($price) {
    if (is_admin()) {
        return $price;
    }
    return '';
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your code a bit? That way others can actually understand it, instead of just copying & pasting something off the internet.

Comment: That hides the price in the whole store, I just need to hide it in the widget.